# How to add button caption on image button

Tags: android, text, imagebutton, caption

I am going to use image button in my app And I need to display button caption on the button I'm using this code but it did not show caption

```
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/try_button"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="@string/trybutton_caption" />
```

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Button` instead of `ImageButton`.

There use:

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/image"
android:text="@string/text"
```

FYI by using `drawableTop`, the drawable will be drawn above the text.

Comment: @Tikitaka it seems you thanked me ,, accepted my answer then accept another answer... anyways .. best of luck

Comment: Sorry friend,I'm still new to Stackoverflow
That is a mistake

Comment: no i didnt asked for the acceptance,I just noted it . You should accept answer when you are confident about it ..

Comment: no friend ,I solved my problem by using your answer
after without knowing i clicked that one sorry

Answer (score 2):

Finally I did that with your help:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/try_button"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="@string/trybutton_caption"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a layout that contains an image view and a text view.  You then use the onClick event of the parent layout to treat it like a button.  Here is an example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/image_button_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="doCustomers"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_box" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Customers" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to create a TextView and set the [compound drawable top](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to your image:

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/custom_button"
```

or through code:

```
textView.setCompoundDrawableWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.custom_button, 0, 0)
```